# Rescue ISO with e4fsck

Tags: linux, centos, ext4

I've got an Oracle Enterprise Linux system, on which I want to convert an ext3 to ext4 partition. This is also the root partition - and I can't unmount it and run e4fsck in the same session.

Is there a rescue ISO out there with e4fsck? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Have you tried an Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: Ubuntu Live CD, Debian Netinstall CD, Arch install CD, all have `e2fsprogs` new enough to understand ext4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for rescue operation I like to use [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/). It is regularly updated and has the latest utilities.

One of the reasons why you are unable to find a rescue CD with `e4fsck` is because Ext4 was an afterthought in RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 and its derivatives (such as Oracle EL) so they had to package the ext4 capable version of the ext2 utilities with a different name. The latest `e2fsck` that comes with any recent rescue disk understands the ext4 format perfectly well.